# Create an unordered list using NSAttributedString in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to create an unordered list using NSAttributedString. I want it in this format:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.

    *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```

I am not sure how can i do this with NSAttributedString.I tried something like this without using NSAttributedString but doesn't seem to be in proper format:

```
     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \n\n" +
     "\t • Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \n" +
     "\t • Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \n" +
     "\t • Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \n\n" +
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"
```

Can anyone help me as to how can I achieve this using NSAtrributedString?

Comment: No idea what you are asking... Do you want to have an array of strings and then have them in a random order?

Comment: I think "unordered list" means "bullet list".

Comment: @EricD. i think you are right. But why unordered?

Comment: @RMenke By comparison to "ordered list" which would be a numbered list, I guess.

Comment: Yes "unordered list" means "bullet list".

Comment: Possibly with NSParagraphStyle, putting each "bullet text" into a specific paragraph with headIndent specific.